# Is OnDestroy reliable in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have a script in which I connect to a socket via TCP and want to use this connection every frame. I need to dispose and clean up after that. My idea was to use `Start()` to start a connection and `OnDestroy()`

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // start TCP connection
    }
    void Update()
    {
        // use connection
    }
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // cleanup
    }
}
```

I need the cleanup to execute whatever happens. Does the `OnDestroy()` method guarantee to be called before the application stops (in standalone mode and in editor) no matter what happens to the object? If not, how can I guarantee the cleanup?

Comment: First remark, sorry for stating the obvious, but nothing is always guaranteed to happen. What if the host suddenly shuts down if you pull the electrical cable? (in case you were wondering if you could risk a temporary unvalid state in a db on your server, for instance, waiting for ondestroy to call something to get back a good state)

Comment: Then, looking at the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html, it seems that `OnDestroy` is called when a scene ends, and if the object was *active*. So inactive objects won't execute it. If user quit the application _ normally_ it should be called. But I would assume it won't get called if for instance some sudden crash happened, or if the user force kill the process.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's why I don't want to establish and dispose the connection every frame, only once

Comment: @ThomasWeller Can't OP use the connection by simply sending requests in an async way, thus there is no need to wait for the answer in the specific frame update? But apart from that, yes, games that are online usually use a more loose protocol like UDP instead of TCP, for the precise reason it has much more reactivity, it doesn't need ACK messages.

Comment: @Pac0 I understand. So what would you suggest for making sure of doing this cleanup?

Comment: I think the safe bet is to have it ready to be handled on the server side. Use some kind of heartbeat to monitor the connection server-client, if it drops, do the cleanup you need to do. It's hard to guess what you absolutely need to do on the client side, I suppose it has to do with the state on the server.

Comment: @Pac0 it sounds reasonable, but then I still have to do the cleanup on the client side, I guess `OnApplicationQuit()` would be suitable for that

Comment: is it something you can do in OnEnable/OnDisable rather than Start/OnDestroy? I would think you would want to be guaranteed that the object will get destroyed to rely on OnDestroy. I would caution against it.

Comment: You need to do cleanup indeed, but you might want to also _recover_ from an abandonned bad state (on startup?) if that makes sense.

Answer (score 13):

No it is not!

Even `OnApplicationQuit` might not get called when your app e.g. crashes for some reason.

And there are other specific cases where neither is called. I know that from my own experience that e.g. on the HoloLens2 apps are not closed but only hibernated. If you then close them via the HoloLens home "menu" then you actually kill them via task manager.

This is pretty dirty and causes neither `OnDestroy` nor `OnApplicationQuit` or any other Unity specific *messages* to be called and we ended up with zomby threads and still occupied TCP ports.

---

If you really want to go sure (e.g. for giving free the connection, killing threads etc) what I finally did was creating a dedicated class with deconstructor ([Finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors))

The deconstructor is pure c# and does not rely on Unity being shutdown correctly so it is guaranteed to be called even if the app was terminated due to a crash as soon as the Garbage Collector automatically does its job.

A `MonoBehaviour` itself shouldn't implement any constructor nor destructor but a private "normal" class can:

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private class FooInternal
    {
        private bool disposed; 

        public FooInternal()
        {
            // create TCP connection
            // start thread etc
        }

        public void Update ()
        {
            // e.g. forward the Update call in order to handle received messages
            // in the Unity main thread
        }

        public ~FooInternal()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if(disposed) return;

            disposed = true; 

            // terminate thread, connection etc
        }
    }

    private FooInternal _internal;

    void Start()
    {
        _internal = new FooInternal ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _internal.Update();
    }

    void OnDestroy ()
    {
        _internal.Dispose();
    }
}
```

if you never pass on the reference to `_internal` to anything else, the GC should automatically kill it after this instance has been destroyed as well.

Comment: I don't think it is good solution. At least you should be very very carefull with it

1) You can't be sure when the destructor will be called. It can be called right after object is destroyed or when application terminated. Even GC.Collect doesn't guarantee anything.

2) It can be unexpectedly called at every moment in the editor. If you remove this component or open other scene, or maybe editor just decide to reload it(you don't know editror internal logic), this object goes to GC heap. And after this, as I mentioned in the firs point, it can be called anyway. It can cause editor crashes.

Comment: @Nikolay well that is exactly the desired behavior in this case (no the crashes) but to be sure that at some point the deconstructor is called and allocated resources definitely released. It is explicitly desired that this happens whenever this component is un/reloaded for whatever reason. It doesn't really matter when exactly it happens but **that** it happens. In my example use cases it was mainly e.g. sockets not getting released correctly if we only rely on `OnDestroy` etc because they might not be called correctly as e.g. in a crash etc .. never caused any Editor crashes so far tbh

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`OnEnable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) for establishing your connection, and [`OnDisable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) for cleaning it up.

The issue with `OnDestroy` (and `OnApplicationQuit` fwiw) is it won't be called if the script is disabled, which can happen if:

- You call `SetActive(false)` on the `GameObject` or any of its parents.
- You set `enabled = false` on the script component.
- You disable the `GameObject` or any of its parents in play mode by unchecking the box in the inspector.
- You disable the script component in play mode by unchecking the box in the inspector.
- The editor is about to recompile the scripts while play mode is running (an especially irritating event to miss for certain types of cleanup code [*cough* [lookin' at you, Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/issues-and-bugs/vuforia-crashes-unity-when-scripts-recompiled-while-running)]).

The issue with `Start` is it won't be called if the script is *re*-enabled after having been disabled (it'll be called the first time, but no more), which happens in all of the cases opposite of the above list (as well as when the editor *finishes* recompilation of scripts in play mode).

On the other hand:

- `OnDisable` will be called when the script transitions to disabled for any of the above reasons, *plus* all the stuff that `OnDestroy` and `OnApplicationQuit` cover.
- `OnEnable` will be called when the script transitions to enabled for any of the above reasons, *plus* all the stuff that `Start` covers.

Additionally, you *will* have a 1:1 correspondence of `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` calls by Unity (of course you can call them yourself whenever you want).

You will only *almost* have a 1:1 correspondence of `Start` and `OnDestroy`: The notable exception is if a script component is *initially* disabled (i.e. you disabled it in edit mode) but its `GameObject` is enabled, you'll still get `OnDestroy` called on the script even if `Start` wasn't called (which may be a bug now that I think about it). Plus, of course, you will miss all the above cases.

`OnEnable` + `OnDisable`, however, handle all that cleanly, and generally do exactly what you hope that they do, in a straightforward manner with (theoretically) no weird quirks or gotchas.

---

For the question itself, yes, `OnDestroy` is reliable: It is called as documented when the script is destroyed.

Of course it wouldn't be called if the application *crashes*, but in general you'd have bigger problems and that's not the kind of thing you normally code around. It also probably wouldn't be called if you exploded a grenade next to the machine running the game but, again, that's all in "undefined behavior" territory.

Comment: To your last point and what is the beginning of my answer: **No!** There are platforms like e.g. Hololens2 that do **never** cleanly invoke `OnApplicationQuit` nor `OnDestroy`! They instead only hibernate the app and only give you the option to basically dirty kill it like via task manager in which case you might end up with some resources not correctly released ;)

Comment: @derHugo So, totally off-topic, but do you know of a way around that on the HL's? I.e. a way to let the Unity app die instead of turning it into a zombie? It's driving me crazy, actually. I've been asking around all over the place (e.g. [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/199844/fully-exiting-hololens-unity-apps-including-closing-the-window))... but everybody seems to back away slowly when they see that question. Only the HL1+2 does it; MagicLeap, MR portal, Android, desktop UWP, iOS, Linux, they all understand that stop means stop, but the HL clearly has boundary issues, heh.

Comment: as said I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65224954/7111561) and so far it worked pretty well for me

Answer (score 0):

OnDestroy and OnApplicationQuit are great functions, in unity, since unity keeps the domain active. Which makes OnDestroy and OnApplicationQuit behave as one would expect.

The issue is that when a OS gets the quit event from the user, it won't wait for OnDestroy to perform all its magic. OnDestroy is in my opinion a great tool for handling life cycles of game objects, but not the life cycle of the application.

Instead what you want to do, is to subscribe to the *WantsToQuit* event, and overwrite its return value. Once you're done with disconnecting and cleaning-up your connections, you turn a flag to true. And call *Application.Quit()* again

You can read more in the unity [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-wantsToQuit.html)

Code Example:

```
public class MyApplicationLifeCycleManager
{
    //Any type of state to safe guard the quitting process
    private bool _allowedToQuit;

    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    static void OnStart()
    {
       Application.wantsToQuit += WantsToQuit;
    }

    private static bool WantsToQuit()
    {
        //This will only allow us to quit the game when the state returns true
        return _allowedToQuit;
    }

    private static async void Cleanup()
    {
       //Do some magic cleanup action, and then turn the flag to true
       _allowedToQuit = true;
       Application.Quit();
    }
}
```